# Xcode 9.4 The file “my_app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode9.4

I'm currently working on a project using Xcode 9.4. I have to reinstall an app on an iPad air 2 because the app doesn't work anymore after the version 11.4.1 of iOS.

When I run the project on the iPad device from Xcode the build is successful but there is a problem just after.
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B3pK.png)

I tried many things like :

- clean and delete derived data
- put the GCC version on "Default compiler (Apple LLVM 9.0)
- check the name on info.plist ([info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwjTA.png))
- copy the file info.plist from a new project
- check if the main.m file is in the compile sources
- put the valid architecture on "arm 64 armv7 armv7s"
- set the target membership on my app ([target membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rPGU.png))
- check the certificate and the provisioning profile
- change the signing section ([project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB15g.png) / [target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbnn3.png) / [target test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NCq.png) / [target UI test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaIiQ.png))

Thank you to read this post. Hope you can help me.

Sincerely.

EDIT : 
[screenshot of frameworks folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYX50.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, and solved by **delete info.plist** file in *framework folder of downloaded by Github*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could the info.plist file be hidden ? Because I don't see any info.plist file in the framework folder.

Comment: @user9962736  can you share screen shot with framework integration in project navigator?

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot of the frameworks folder. Is it what you're looking for ?